# Add dynamically input text and buttons in activity android

Tags: android, android-layout, dynamic

I have an application with an input text where the users have to insert an information and a button "+" beside to input text.
I would like to make my form dynamic in a way that when a user pushes on "+" button appears dynamically another text input and another "+" button beside this one, the process is  repeated in the same way.

I created and xml file, sample_content:

```
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/attempt"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:text="TextView" />

            <Button
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="36dp"
                android:layout_height="32dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="22dp"
                android:text="+" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="229dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="14dp"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/addKey"
                android:background="@drawable/inputtext_corner"
                android:ems="10"
                android:textSize="18sp" >

                <requestFocus />

            </EditText>

        </RelativeLayout>
```

and in my Activity, AddDeviceActivity I put:

```
                inflater = LayoutInflater.from(AddDeviceActivity.this);
                Button addKey = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addKey);

                addKey.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        final RelativeLayout canvas = (RelativeLayout) AddDeviceActivity.this.findViewById(R.id.my_canvas);
                        final View childView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sample_component, canvas, false);
                        //  TODO: Look up the 5 different signatures of the addView method, 
                        //  and pick that best fits your needs
                        canvas.addView(childView);
                    }
                });
```

But this solution doesn't work because when I add the first input text and the first button,  I don't know how to make the second button work in my AddDeviceActivity dynamicly

Answer (score 0):

Just wondering whether you can do this:

Have your activity implement `OnClickListener` and add this method to your activity:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    final RelativeLayout canvas = (RelativeLayout) AddDeviceActivity.this.findViewById(R.id.my_canvas);
    final View childView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sample_component, canvas, false);
    canvas.addView(childView);
    ((Button)childView.findViewById(R.id.addKey)).setOnClickListener(AddDeviceActivity.this);
}
```

And then change your initial code to use

```
addKey.setOnClickListener(this);
```

instead of an anonymous inner class.

I haven't tested this, but don't see why it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

check out this, pass `null` instead of `canvas` object in `inflate()` method

```
 addKey.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            final RelativeLayout canvas = (RelativeLayout) AddDeviceActivity.this.findViewById(R.id.my_canvas);
                            final View childView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sample_component, null, false);
                            //  TODO: Look up the 5 different signatures of the addView method, 
                            //  and pick that best fits your needs
                            canvas.addView(childView);
                        }
                    });
```